# iostat vs /proc/diskstats

Tags: linux, performance, iostat

I want to monitor the io performance of a linux system, particularly the read performance.
The iostat command gives await and svctim for both reads and writes combined which is not suitable for me.

The file /proc/diskstats gives in column 1 the # of reads completed and in column 4 the # milliseconds spent reading. Columns 
I would figure that column 4 divided by column 1 would give me the average read time.
My idea is to sample it every x seconds and do the calculation.

For the writes I will take columns 5 and 8.

Is this the right approach?
Are the any caveats?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you read iostat's man page? There are r_await and w_await columns. svctim is deprecated

Comment: Yes I have on OEL 5 and OEL 6.  
The r_await and w_await are not mentioned in the iostat manpage.